# Complex collections depending on Frontmatter headers and it's value?

Tags: twig, grav

Include partial view with a complex collection:

```
{% include 'partials/article-main.html.twig' with {'page': #here goes condition} %}
```

How can i choose all pages, that has a field named `main_article` in the headers/Frontmatter set to true?

Comment: Reason for down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use Collection for search a specific attribute in page, so you need to get a Collection (eg for all pages), create a `for` loop to check if `main_article` is available in a page and decide what to do with that page.

If doing that, you can't get an array of the pages which have `main_article` attribute because removing element in a Twig array is painful. Twig is a template engine anyway.

So if you want to do in a better way and have ease in maintenance, you can build a custom plugin, do everything you need in the plugin with PHP and deliver the final array of pages to Twig.